# Tensorflow versions other than 2.12 cannot be installed on my windows computer

Tags: python, tensorflow

Since tensorflow>2.10 does not support gpu on windows with native windows (virtualenv), I tried to install tensorflow 2.10 .
however, it seems that only version 2.12 is available:

> C:\Users\Ziv>pip install tensorflow==2.10
>
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> tensorflow==2.10 (from versions: 2.12.0rc0, 2.12.0rc1, 2.12.0) ERROR:
> No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.10

any help would be appreciated

Comment: I suspect you are using python 3.11. TensorFlow 2.10 has pre-compiled packages on Pypi for python 3.7, 3.8, 3.9 and 3.10, see the [list of archives on Pypi](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.10.0/#files). Downgrade your python version to one of those.